# COMO FUNCIONAN LAS VARIABLES DE ENTORNO EN EL CONTEXTO DE REACT Y ARCHIVOS ESTÁTICOS?

Tags: reactjs

Perdón por la ignorancia. Esta duda me carcome desde hace tiempo y no he encontrado información al respecto. Podemos usar variables de entorno para aplicaciones node js, según el sistema operativo donde estas se ejecutan. Pero en el caso del build de react, que son archivos estáticos, estos se cargan en el navegador del cliente, de dónde obtiene el valor de por ejemplo proccess.env.REACT_APP_URL_API que se encuentre en .env, si esta variable no está en la computadora cliente. ¿En dónde se almacena el valor de esa variable de entorno al hacer build? ¿Cómo funcionan las variables de entorno en react?

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#referencing-environment-variables-in-the-html

Comment: No están en el equipo del cliente, sino que están en el servidor desde el que se sirven estos archivos que llamas *estáticos*. Por ejemplo, si tu despliegue lo haces para que sea servido por un servidor Apache, nginx, Tomcat, o el que elijas, las variables de entorno las toma desde el S.O. en el que se ejecuta dicho servidor, y no desde el archivo `.env`, cuyo propósito en este caso es inyectar variables de entorno durante el desarrollo.